# Passing variables from a Phonegap app to an Android service

Tags: android, cordova

I have a Phonegap app with a login form. The login function uses localStorage.setItem() to store the language of the user once they log in, so that the next time they open the app, the screens before the login can try to guess what language the user is going to want everything in. It doesn't matter that localStorage could potentially be erased as this isn't critical data - it'll just fall back to English if need be. Perfect for my needs really.

Outside of Phonegap, there's also another service that runs in the background and upon specific user actions, automatically initiates a call to a static phone number + launches one of the Phonegap screens. The code for this is as follows:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);

Intent emergencyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EmergencyActivity.class);
emergencyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(emergencyIntent);
```

This all works perfectly, except that we've decided to no longer use a static number for the automated call. Instead, each user is assigned something specific. I've therefore now amended the login function to also store the relevant phone number and need to amend the above code to read this variable when making the call. Again it's not a major issue if localStorage is erased because we can always fall back onto a generic number if need be, but I can't find a way of reading this variable outside of Phonegap...

Since it's possible to use getApplicationContext() to initiate the Phonegap activity, as per the other piece of code in this same routine, I'm wondering if I just need to reverse the order of these two blocks and somehow get the variable from emergencyIntent? Or is there a more elegant solution?

As always, any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just doing window.location.href = 'tel:' + localStorage.getItem('emergencyPhone'); from within the JS of the started activity. Not ideal, but it works.

I also found https://github.com/anemitoff/PhoneGap-PhoneDialer which would add the ability to automate the actual dial, the same way my original callIntent method worked, but I decided this may trigger too many accidental calls so opted against integration. Perhaps useful to others though.